# guidelines on usage of size_t and offset_t?

Tags: c++

This is probably a C++ 101 question: I'm curious what the guidelines are for using `size_t` and `offset_t`, e.g. what situations they are intended for, what situations they are not intended for, etc. I haven't done a lot of portable programming, so I have typically just used something like `int` or `unsigned int` for array sizes, indexes, and the like. However, I gather it's preferable to use some of these more standard typedefs when possible, so I'd like to know how to do that properly.

As a follow-up question, for development on Windows using Visual Studio 2008, where should I look to find the actual typedefs? I've found `size_t` defined in a number of headers within the VS installation directory, so I'm not sure which of those I should use, and I can't find `offset_t` anywhere.

Comment: Interesting answers - maybe I'm wrong about `offset_t` being "standard"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are probably referring to `off_t`, not `offset_t`. `off_t` is a POSIX type, not a C type, and it is used to denote file offsets (allowing 64-bit file offsets even on 32-bit systems). C99 has superceded that with `fpos_t`.

`size_t` is meant to count bytes or array elements. It matches the address space.

Comment: size_t has the size needed to contains the size of the largest object, not necessarily the whole address space (think about 16 bit segmented architectures).

Comment: @AProgrammer: I deliberately used the vague "matches" to describe how size_t is related to the address space. You are right: size_t is defined to be the result type of the sizeof operator.

Comment: Sounds like I should be using size_t for the purposes you describe, and not messing with offset_t. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `offset_t` do you mean `ptrdiff_t`? This is the type returned by such routines as `std::distance`. My understanding is that `size_t` is unsigned (to match the address space as previously mentioned) whereas `ptrdiff_t` is signed (to theoretically denote "backwards" distances between pointers, though this is very rarely used).

Comment: Interesting addition to the discussion - I wasn't aware of ptrdiff_t, but it sounds useful.

Answer (score 1):

`offset_t` isn't mentioned at all in my copy of the C++ standard.

`size_t` on the other hand, is meant simply to denote object or array sizes. A `size_t` is guaranteed to be big enough to store the size of any in-memory object, so it should be used for that.

Answer (score 1):

You use `size_t` whenever the C++ language specification indicates that it is used in a particular expression. For example, you'd use `size_t` to store the return value of `sizeof`, or to represent the number of elements in an array (`new[]` takes `size_t`).

I've no idea what `offset_t` is - it's not mentioned once in ISO C++ spec.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging an old one back up... offset_t (which is a long long) is used by Solaris' llseek() system call, and is to be used anywhere you're likely to run into real 64-bit file offsets... meaning you're working with really **huge** files.